# __repr__ implementation in Linked List in python

Tags: python

This is my implementation of a Singly Linked List. I'm trying to test the custom implementation of the print method by writing my own `__repr__`

```
class SList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def insert(self, item):
        if not item:
            raise ValueError('Cannot add None item to a list')
        self.size += 1
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(item)
        else:
            p = Node(item)
            p.next = self.root
            self.root = p

    """Remove the element at the specific index"""

    def remove(self, index):
        if index < 0 or index >= self.size:
            raise ValueError('Index cannot be negative or greater than the size of the list')

        current = self.root
        if index == 0:
            self.root = self.root.next
        else:
            for _ in range(index - 1):
                current = current.next
            p = current.next.next
            if p is not None:
                current.next = p
            else:
                current.next = None

        self.size -= 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __repr__(self):
        "[{}]".format(", ".join(map(str, self)))

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.root
        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current.next


class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError('Node cannot be instantiated without an item')
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
```

This is where I call the function.

```
def main():
   l = SList()
   l.insert(12)
   l.insert(11)
   l.insert(2)
   l.insert(21)
   print(l)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/username/Dropbox/code/pydev/data_structures/app.py", line 12, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/usernamei/Dropbox/code/pydev/data_structures/app.py", line 9, in main
        print(l)
    TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

However I'm clearly returning a formatted string from the `__repr__` method. Is my implemetation of `__iter__` incorrect? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see a `return` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement. Change it to:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "[{}]".format(", ".join(map(str, self)))
```

If you won't mention it explicitly, python treats the return as `None`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `str` for a `Node` object, that doesn't have it (could be a `None`, but won't be a problem, since `None` has `str` implemented).

Implement `__str__` for `Node` (add this line in the `Node` class):

```
def __str__ (self):
    return str(self.data)
```

Also, add `return` (functions returns `None` by default):

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "[{}]".format(", ".join(map(str, self)))
```